# Why does the following script delete itself?

Tags: shell-script, files, rm, executable, shebang

If you create an executable file with the following contents, and run it, it will delete itself.
How does this work?

```
#!/bin/rm
```

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28685/11259)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Heh, that was my first thought when I saw this.

Comment: it's not about `rm`, it is about the `#!`. The question could be rephrased to how does any executable script with a `#!` works.

Comment: How did you manage to stumble upon this?

Comment: @user1717828 Probably [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28685/43394).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The kernel interprets the line starting with `#!` and uses it to run the script, passing in the script's name; so this ends up running

```
/bin/rm scriptname
```

which deletes the script. (As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) [points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280778/why-does-the-following-bash-script-delete-itself/280780?noredirect=1#comment488891_280780), `scriptname` here is sufficient to find the script — if you specified a relative or absolute path, that's passed in as-is, otherwise whatever path was found in `PATH` is prepended, including possibly the emptry string if your `PATH` contains that and the script is in the current directory. You can play around with an echo script — `#!/bin/echo` — to see how this works.)

As [hobbs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1215/hobbs) pointed out, this means your script is actually an `rm` script, not a `bash` script — the latter would start with `#!/bin/bash`.

See [How programs get run](https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/) for details of how this works in Linux; the comments on that article give details for other platforms. `#!` is called a shebang, you'll find lots of information by searching for that term (thanks to [Aaron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/139867/aaron) for the suggestion). As [jlp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20700/jlp) pointed out, you'll also find it referred to as "pound bang" or "hash bang" (`#` is commonly known as "pound" — in countries that don't use `£` — or "hash", and `!` as "bang"). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) has more info.

Comment: Reminds me of ol' [CrunchBang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrunchBang_Linux)

Comment: "passing in the script's name" -- not quite.  That's how it worked in the 70s, but it invites a race condition hack.  You can start a script with one heading, or set of file permissions, then change it before the interpreter is started.  Instead, I believe such files are opened and read by the OS, then LEFT opened and passed to the interpreter as file handle 2 (or 0?).  I'm not 1000% sure of this so I won't edit the actual answer

Comment: @SwissFrank yes, there is a race, and yes, there are loaders (in the Linux kernel) which support passing an open file descriptor, but [not for scripts](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/binfmt_script.c#L108). In fact, if the race were fixed for scripts, arbitrary commands would no longer work as shebangs, and `rm` couldn’t be used in this way.